# Production build not displaying model property values correctly

Tags: html, css, angular, .net-core

I am working on a project that has and **Angular 10** front end and a Dot Net Core 3.1 API.

When *debugging/developing* the system, one the screens displays a model property, a string called name, correctly.

However, whenever I run `ng build --prod` the same screen cuts off the property value. Each value returned appears to have the last 7 characters missing.

The code for the HTML is below:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of versionDocItems">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col pt-1 filterName ml-3 align-self-center">
        {{item.name | titlecase}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <button class="btn blue backButton filterButton" (click)="download(item.itemFileId)" type="submit" name="applyFilter">Download</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>                   
</div>
```

The CSS seems to be fine and shows that there is plenty of space left for the property to show.

Also when I have used `console.log` to return property values they are returning correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd say you have to track down the problem, right now the problem is to wide to give you an answer. Is the DOM/produced HTML in your browser the same between dev mode and prod mode? If yes, then it is definitely an UI problem and it likely comes from something different in your CSS bundle.

Comment: Agreeing with the comment above me and there is nothing wrong with the shown code. I recommend removing some of the css classes and the `titlecase` pipe and see if any of this fixes your problem.

Comment: The only differences I can see in the PROD and DEV HTML output is this:
DEV - _ngcontent-txw-c122
PROD - _ngcontent-pca-c57
at the beginning of each div